# How to restore/refresh Database from D365 PROD/UAT environment to Development Environment?

Tags: axapta, database-backups, dynamics-365-operations

I need to perform testing on data similar to production, but can't get the backup of that on local for dev testing

I tried to see the documentations, but not able to find exact answer, followed this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/database/database-refresh

But not got what I required, so can anyone write exact steps to follow to perform this activity?

Comment: The linked article describes the first of multiple steps to get a backup from a production environment to a development environment. Could you explain in more detail what part of the article is giving you trouble? Note that after that step, you still need to [export the database from UAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/database/export-database) and then [import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/database/import-database) it on the dev environment.